# Is using the word "Likewise" in a sentence not professional or informal?

Tags: word-usage, sentence, formality

Last evening in my communication class, we had some discussion. In that discussion I used the word likewise in a sentence. But they said using likewise in a sentence anywhere is not professional or it is informal if we use likewise in a sentence. But I'm not convinced. Can anyone of you let me know is it correct or not with some details.

Comment: *Likewise* can be used either formally or informally. And if you use it in a complete sentence, rather than as a single-word utterance, you are likely using it in a way that is eminently compatible with formal register. "She always returned her students' papers within a week, and encouraged her colleagues to do likewise" is perfectly good formal-register English.

Comment: Since the issue surrounds a particular sentence, please post that sentence.

Comment: @BrianDonovan  Thank you. I will ask this in my class today

Comment: @Lawrence But they said, using it in any sentence in corporate world is not professional

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan If you're happy with their opinion, that's fine, but I thought you wanted to know *this* community's opinion on the matter. As others have posted, it depends - sometimes it's professional, sometimes it's not. There are some guidelines, but we can't say for sure whether it's informal in *your* case because you haven't told us what *your* case is. After all, your sentence may turn out to be informal because of something unrelated to the word *likewise*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise) says it is used in informal contexts for the third definition as shown. Otherwise it is okay for formal use.

> in the same way
>
> in addition
>
> —used in informal speech to say that you share the feelings that someone else has just expressed

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/likewise) dictionary says likewise.

> **FORMAL** in the same way, or in a similar way
>   *"The character of the lake has changed and the character of the surrounding area likewise ".*
>
> **SPOKEN** used for expressing the same thing that someone has just said to you.
>   *"Have a good weekend." "Likewise"*

So it finally depends on what exactly your sentence was.

Comment: Edits have improved this answer.